# "Collection was modified; enumeration operation .." error when removing a column

Tags: 2013, development, ssom, console-application

I have wrote the following code inside my console application, the purpose is to loop through all the current sub-sites, and then loop through all the current lists. If the default list view contain a field called "global1" or "global2" to remove it from the view:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(scurl))  //site collection url
            {
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(subsiteurl0)) //specific subsite url
            {
      SPWebCollection subWebs = web.Webs; //get all sites under specific subsites

  foreach (SPWeb subSite in subWebs)
                 {


      var l = subSite.Lists;
      var ll = l;
      foreach (SPList l2 in ll)
      {
         var defaultview = l2.DefaultView;
         if (defaultview != null)
         {
             if (defaultview.ViewFields.SchemaXml.Contains("global1"))
             {
                 defaultview.ViewFields.Delete("global1"); // #use internal column name
                 defaultview.Update();
             }
             if (defaultview.ViewFields.SchemaXml.Contains("global2"))
             {
                 defaultview.ViewFields.Delete("global2"); // #use internal column name
                 defaultview.Update();
             }

         }
      }
```

When I run this console application and a column is deleted from the list view, I will get the following exception :

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

When the next loop iteration is reached :

```
 foreach (SPList l2 in ll)
```

Comment: Try to seperate the logic. Maybe first search for the fields and add it to some dictionary or string array. And at the end run the delete Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do it like this, using a `for` statement instead of a `foreach` statement:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(scurl))  //site collection url
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(subsiteurl0)) //specific subsite url
    {
        var websCount = web.Webs.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < websCount; i++)
        {
            var subSite = web.Webs[i];

            var listsCount = subSite.Lists.Count;
            for (var j = 0; j < listsCount; j++)
            {
                var l2 = subSite.Lists[j];
                var defaultview = l2.DefaultView;
                if (defaultview != null)
                {
                    if (defaultview.ViewFields.SchemaXml.Contains("global1"))
                    {
                        defaultview.ViewFields.Delete("global1"); // #use internal column name
                        defaultview.Update();
                    }
                    if (defaultview.ViewFields.SchemaXml.Contains("global2"))
                    {
                        defaultview.ViewFields.Delete("global2"); // #use internal column name
                        defaultview.Update();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
You cannot modify the collection using a foreach loop. You must use another technique like a for loop to get items in the collection.

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and its behavior is undefined.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwyysy67(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: but why i am getting the error when using `foreach`? could this error trying to indicate something important to me i should not do inside my list views?? ,, i mean if i use `for` instead of `foerach` then i can remove the field from the list views correctly.. but maybe i should try to fix the exception when using `foreach()`  rather than simply replace `foreach()`  with  `for` to achieve this? did you understand my point ,, so can i keep using `foreach()` but overcome this exception ?

Comment: "An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined."

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwyysy67(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This means, that you cannot modify the collection using a foreach loop. You must use another technique like a for loop to get items in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a collection using a foreach loop. Use a for loop.

On a mobile so hard to type this out. Try:

```
for(var l1 = 0; l1 < subSite.Lists.Count; l1++)
{
     var defaultview = l1.DefaultView;
     if (defaultview != null)
     {
         if (defaultview.ViewFields.SchemaXml.Contains("global1"))
         {
             defaultview.ViewFields.Delete("global1"); // #use internal column name
             defaultview.Update();
         }
         if (defaultview.ViewFields.SchemaXml.Contains("global2"))
         {
             defaultview.ViewFields.Delete("global2"); // #use internal column name
             defaultview.Update();
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, but a code sample might be helpful.

Comment: @Bunzab can you advice how i can use for loop instead of foreach in my case? and which foreach you are talking about?

Comment: The second one. See the edit.

Comment: @Bunzab but i need to access the lists based on the id is this correct ? something such as "var defaultview = l1[i].DefaultView;" ? is this correct?

Comment: @Bunzab please update your code so i can accept it ...

Comment: @Bunzab thanks for the reply..but first of all why i am getting the error when using `foreach`? could this error indicate something important to me that i should not do inside my list views? ,, i mean if i use `for` instead of `foerach` then i can remove the field from the list views correctly.. but maybe i should try to fix the exception when using `foreach()`  rather than simply replace `foreach()`  with  `for` to achieve this? did you understand my point ,, so can i keep using `foreach()` but overcome this exception ?

Comment: @Cecilia gave a good answer and follow up comment.